# Symfony: generate prod url in dev environment

Tags: symfony, routes

I am wondering if it is possible to choose environment when generating urls with the symfony routing component.

In a controller

```
$this->generateUrl($route, $params);
```

generates `/` in prod envrionment and `/app_dev.php` in dev.

There doesn't seem to be a parameter for the environment so that you could generate productive urls in dev environment. I just don't want to use something like str_replace all the time.

This would be great:

```
$this->generateUrl($route, $params, 'prod');
```

For your understanding, I am working on a cms project where I have to match uris against the database where they are stored without app_dev.php.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sure that you can override `Router` by own, but I don't think that there is native function to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

More of a hack than a proper solution, you can set the Context's $baseUrl to be '' (as it would in production environment) before calling the generateUrl and reset-ting it back after the call. The RequestContext->getBaseUrl is consulted each time the complete Url is built.

In our case, we had to build Urls without the app_dev or app.php because our frontend was an AngularJS based application matching the URLs. In this case, since we dint want the app_dev or app.php at all, we created an EventListener that  does a

```
$this->router->getContext()->setBaseUrl('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Router component workflow doesn't include any of **app.php** or **app_dev.php** files. It only works with the pattern which comes after php file in the query string, whatever that file is.

So you're not able to do that. You only can use **.htaccess** file config to manage what file will be used as a default one, no more.